# Create a 3D ply file with faces and vertices from numpy array containing vertices

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, open3d

I have the following set of vertices and i would like to create a 3D ply file that have lines and vertices(it would be great to also have faces)

```
 vertices = 
[[ 2.304688  -1.882748  -2.1874995]
 [-3.007812   1.6       -2.1875005]
 [-3.007812  -1.882748  -2.1875005]
 [ 2.304688  -1.882748  -2.1874995]
 [ 2.304688   1.6       -2.1874995]
 [-3.007812   1.6       -2.1875005]
 [-3.007812  -1.882748  -2.1875005]
 [-3.007813   1.6        2.9687495]
 [-3.007813  -1.882748   2.9687495]
 [-3.007812  -1.882748  -2.1875005]
 [-3.007812   1.6       -2.1875005]
 [-3.007813   1.6        2.9687495]
 [-3.007813  -1.882748   2.9687495]
 [ 2.304687   1.6        2.9687505]
 [ 2.304687  -1.882748   2.9687505]
 [-3.007813  -1.882748   2.9687495]
 [-3.007813   1.6        2.9687495]
 [ 2.304687   1.6        2.9687505]
 [ 2.304687  -1.882748   2.9687505]
 [ 2.304688   1.6       -2.1874995]
 [ 2.304688  -1.882748  -2.1874995]
 [ 2.304687  -1.882748   2.9687505]
 [ 2.304687   1.6        2.9687505]
 [ 2.304688   1.6       -2.1874995]
 [ 2.304687   1.6        2.9687505]
 [-3.007813   1.6        2.9687495]
 [-3.007812   1.6       -2.1875005]
 [-3.007812   1.6       -2.1875005]
 [ 2.304688   1.6       -2.1874995]
 [ 2.304687   1.6        2.9687505]]
```

Right now I can create a a ply file containing the vertices using the following:

```
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(vertices)
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```

When I display it in Open3D i can obviously only see the vertices. I would like to be able to see also the lines and the faces if it is possible.

[image]
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to restruct a mesh from its vertices only. What you can do is create mesh of the *convex hull* of the points. Check out [SciPy's Delaunay](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html).

For writing PLY files (and many other formats), you can use [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio). (Disclaimer: I wrote meshio.)

Comment: What else do I need other than points to create the Mesh? I have the order in which the point need to be connected. Is that enough?

Comment: Well, you can create _a_ mesh with just the points. Try scipy.spatial.delaunay.

Comment: There is nothing similar in Open3D? Because my end goal it to be able to export the mesh as a point cloud